# Trying to update an entry in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a record in my database using the code below. I'm trying to change the product name but I am getting the following error:

```
Could not update data: Unknown column 'Earrings' in 'field list'
```

Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $dbhost = 'databasehost';
    $dbuser = 'username';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn )
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $ProductsID = $_POST['ProductsID'];
        $ProductsName = $_POST['ProductsName'];

        $sql = "UPDATE Products ".
           "SET ProductsName = $ProductsName ".
           "WHERE ProductsID = $ProductsID" ;

        mysql_select_db('databasename');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
        if(! $retval )
        {
            die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Updated data successfully\n";
        mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE Products ".
       "SET ProductsName = '$ProductsName' ".
       "WHERE ProductsID = $ProductsID" ;
```

You forgot to wrap `$ProductName` with quotations. Don't forget to do so when dealing with string values.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
ProductsName = '$ProductsName'
```

Also, be sure to escape that input, else you'll be subjected to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sanitizing your data, so there is a good chance that your query could break depending on the value submitted, not to mention it leaves your database wide open for an attacker to manipulate via [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Please do not use mysql_ functions, as they are depricated. You should be using prepared statements, please see [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) and [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli).

As for your answer, you need to put 'quotes' around the $variable

Comment: I can't believe people keep repeating "use mysqli instead of mysql", which is totally unimportant, and do not even tell him how unsecure his code is.

Comment: I told him to use prepared statements which would avoid SQL injections. Three of the four answers here tell him to escape his data..if you don't think that is enough, you are more than welcome to keep commenting about how insecure it is.

Comment: Actually if someone comes here looking for a similar answer, he'll only read the first, and eventually the second answer, but not all of them. So obviously the accepted answer has to be as complete as possible.

Comment: @Virus721: It's not totally unimportant, ext/mysql is on the verge of dying: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to set the ProductsName to an existing column, add quotes to let sql interpret a value:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Products ".
       "SET ProductsName = '$ProductsName' ".
       "WHERE ProductsID = $ProductsID" ;
```